# A knowledge quiz with several questions in Sets

Tags: python

I would like to add more questions to the knowledge quiz program and I am stuck at this point. As can be seen from this code, the knowledge quiz consists of one question, which is summarized in a set.
planets = {'Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars'}

For example, would like to group and query more questions in a set such as:
europäischen_union = {'Belgien', 'Bulgarien', 'Deutschland', 'Frankreich'}
dax_companies ={'Adidas', 'Airbus', 'Allianz', 'BASF'}
and so on ...

```
planeten = {'Merkur', 'Venus', 'Erde', 'Mars'}
planetenx = {''}
richtige = 0
versuche = 0

print('List all the planets in our solar system!')
while planeten != set():
    eingabe = input('Planet: ')
    if eingabe in planeten and eingabe not in planetenx:
        planeten = planeten - {eingabe}
        planetenx.add(eingabe)
        print('Richtig!')
        print(planetenx)
        richtige += 1
        versuche += 1

    elif eingabe not in planeten and eingabe in planetenx:
        print('Sorry!', eingabe, 'we already had')
        versuche += 1

    else:
        print('Sorry!', eingabe, 'is not a planet')
        versuche += 1

print('Congratulations. You have listed all the planets.')
print(richtige, 'richtige Antworten, in ', versuche, 'Versuchen')
```

It would be very helpful if someone could add me the code here as described by me above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
fragen = ['List all the planets in our solar system!',
         'List all countries in the European Union!',
         'List all DAX companies!']

antwortsätze = [{'Merkur', 'Venus', 'Erde', 'Mars'},
             {'Belgien', 'Bulgarien', 'Deutschland', 'Frankreich'},
             {'Adidas', 'Airbus', 'Allianz', 'BASF'}]

for frage, antworten in zip(fragen, antwortsätze):
    antwortenx = set()
    richtige = 0
    versuche = 0
    print(frage)
    
    while antworten:
        eingabe = input('Answer: ')
        if eingabe == '':
            continue
        elif eingabe in antwortenx:
            print('Sorry!', eingabe, 'we already had')
        elif eingabe in antworten:
            antworten.remove(eingabe)
            antwortenx.add(eingabe)
            print('Richtig!')
            print("Korrekte Antworten:", ', '.join(antwortenx))
            richtige += 1
        else:
            print('Sorry!', eingabe, 'is not correct')
        versuche += 1

    print('Question Complete.')
    print(richtige, 'richtige Antworten, in ', versuche, 'Versuchen')
```